# Can't Access My project Classes inside installed pod class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, cocoapods

The problem is as follows.

I created a public class `cls` in my project `XProject`, then installed a pod named `justPod`

This pod has a class `PodClass`, in which I want to declare an object of `cls`.

However, `PodClass` can't see `cls`, so it can't use it as a data type to declare an object!

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to go is to create an extension of `PodClass` within your project and, inside that extension, define a **computed property** with a getter and a setter of type `cls`.